# Detect compression in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

Normally one would detect if compression was requested by checking the Accept-Encoding request header. Google App Engine strips this header. Is there any other way to detect this kind of thing? I would like to know if GAE will compress particular responses before they're sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to use another server to detect compression.

I've broken my pages into an initialization stub and the content. The stub includes a bit that causes the browser to make a request to the third-party server solely for compression detection. If that passes, it then loads and injects the content.

This is not optimal, but it does work and has cut traffic from irresponsible bots by quite a bit without having significant impact on users.

**Edit:** It occurs to me that it may be possible to infer this from the client side. Using AJAX and checking the `Content-Encoding` response header for `gzip` would mean that GAE thinks the client wanted compression which implies that the client asked for compression.

```js
// Certain files aren't compressed by GAE even if requested so 'canary' 
// needs to be of a type and size to trigger compression
$.get('canary').done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  // request succeeded
  var contentEncoding = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Encoding');
  if(contentEncoding != null) {
    if(!['gzip','deflate','sdch','br'].every(function(v,i,a){
      return contentEncoding.indexOf(v) < 0;
    })) {
      // accepted compression found, initiate remainder of page load
      return;
    }
  }
  // no acceptable compression, kill page
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
  // request failed, kill page
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[GAE does this automatically](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#compression), you don't need to worry about it in your app:

> Google App Engine does its best to serve gzipped content to browsers
>   that support it. Taking advantage of this scheme is automatic and
>   requires no modifications to applications.
>
> We use a combination of request headers (Accept-Encoding, User-Agent)
>   and response headers (Content-Type) to determine whether or not the
>   end-user can take advantage of gzipped content. This approach avoids
>   some well-known bugs with gzipped content in popular browsers. To
>   force gzipped content to be served, clients may supply 'gzip' as the
>   value of both the Accept-Encoding and User-Agent request headers.
>   Content will never be gzipped if no Accept-Encoding header is present.

And headers can be checked on the actual msgs to/from a GAE app (in production only, the dev server **doesn't** perform the compression). I see (in firefox):

On the request:

> Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"

On the response:

> Content-Enconding: "gzip"

Comment: I'm aware of this. I've noted that it appears that poorly coded or aging bots seem to be the main requesters not asking for compressed content. They go so far as to forge User-Agent. I'd prefer to deny these clients access rather than serve up quota-eating content. As for the Accept-Encoding header, it doesn't make it as far as the app itself. Part of Google handling compression, I imagine.

Comment: That's fine. The question, though, is: Is there any other way for the app to detect that compression was requested (or detect that GAE would apply compression)?

Comment: you can block such bots in `robots.txt`, or, if it's not enough, setup DoS Protection for this IPs

Comment: @IgorArtamonov The bots in question ignore robots.txt and just not requesting compression wouldn't be seen as a DoS attack.